# Connect Excel PowerPivot to SSAS using HTTP access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerpivot, http-module, ssas

Need to connect PowerPivot to SSAS using HTPP access. The Table Import Wizard gives the error below when Importing data to PowerPivot (just from the client machine, its works just fine for me!).

> An unexpected error occurred (file ‘pfoledbprops.cpp’, line 479,
>   function ‘PFDBPropsOledb::MapPropertyToOledb’). A connection could not
>   be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of
>   ‘c68b8491-be1b-4c6a-a56f-7b2b2a53164b’, Name of ‘tet’. An error
>   occurred while processing table ‘Query’. The current operation was
>   cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed. Out of
>   line object ‘DataSource’, referring to ID(s)
>   ‘c68b8491-be1b-4c6a-a56f-7b2b2a53164b’, has been specified but has not
>   been used. Out of line object ‘DataSourceView’, referring to ID(s)
>   ‘Temp_DSV’, has been specified but has not been used.

Someone could help me please!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of ‘c68b8491-be1b-4c6a-a56f-7b2b2a53164b’, Name of ‘tet’.

This indicates that there's a possible login issue. Ensure that you have specified a domain account with proper permissions to the data source `tet`.

The same with pictures: https://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/ssas-a-connection-could-not-be-made-to-the-data-source-with-the-datasourceid/

Comment: Thanks for youre reply.
I already specified a domain account for the data source, and i could connect from my machine.
The problem is with the client machine!
ps : the client uses the same account as me to test, but the wizard gives him the error message.

Comment: @soukaouta could you try to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` above the line starting with `INSERT` and see if that helps.

Comment: the `SET NOCOUNT ON` didn't resolve the problem